# Other meaning of 一顿 besides relating to meals

Tags: translation, complement

I have the following sentence:

`老师把学生批评了一顿`

Google's only translation of `一顿` on its own returns 'A meal' or 'a spanking' which is the meaning discussed in other posts.

Here it seems like it means a little bit, or slightly, but can anyone offer a clearer picture?

For references, I took it from [Peking Uni Youtube class for HSK5](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tzXD21lZEzU&list=PLVWfp7qXLmKWC76M9btbnLRauUwSE14mZ&index=28) (5:22)

Comment: 批评 can be seen as spanking by language.

Comment: 一顿 usually indicates "enough amount of", instead of "a little of". This student must have suffered a lot if you say "批评了一顿".

Comment: @River Don't want to argue, but 一顿 doesn't necessarily indicate the sense of 'enough'. To me, it's just a normal measure word for 打，揍，批评，etc.  'enough' or 'suffer a lot' might be a bit overstated, but that could be just me.

Comment: @dan I agree,  一頓飯 in Cantonese is 一餐飯, with 餐 as the classifier for 'dinner' and dinner can be big or small, long or short. 揍了一頓 = 打咗 一餐

Comment: example: 他被打了一顿 > 他被打了一下. For a big or small meal, if you consider it as a meal it is a meal. But for spanking, it has to be accumulated to a certain amount to be considered as a session.

Comment: @River Yeah, you got some point there. That accumulation might not be up to "suffer a lot". That's why I said it's a 'BIT' overstated. Actually, if you think it deep, any measure word should accumulate the enough amount to be one unit. 顿 is probably a vague word because we don't really have criteria to judge how much it should be for 顿. People might take "批评了一顿" differently in terms of severity, and some might not think they have "suffer a lot" from "批评了一顿". As for 一顿饭，we don't know how much one has eaten when they say 我刚吃了一顿饭. So, for safe, I'd just take 顿 as a normal measure word.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Taiwan, according to dictionary owned by Ministry of Education.

[一頓](http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=Z00000149088) means:

> 表示數量，一次、一回。

(Denote quantity, one session.)

Comment: [zdic](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E4%B8%80%E9%A1%BF) has the same definition

Answer (score 0):

一顿 means " a big amount", "enough amount"...

e.g.

- 狠狠 `揍/批评/打` 他 一顿 ( bit a lot )
- 使劲吃了一顿大餐  ( eat a lot )

OK, there's a exception:

- 我吃了一顿饭.  (I eat a meal.   not so much or so less)

In other case:

- 爸爸打了儿子一顿.  ( means bit a lot)

Comment: I see in your example 使劲吃了一顿大餐 means "eat a lot".  However, if I only say: 我吃了一顿饭，how do you know I've eaten a big amount of food? 一顿 itself doesn't connote anything big.  However, the words 狠狠, 使劲, 大餐 makes it a big deal.